# AWS DynamoDB filter expression to filter by a particular field in an object within a list

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Suppose I have the following database schema for each item:

```
{
 config: [
   {
    value1: "value_1"
    value2: "value_2"
   }
 ]
}
```

For each item in the database, there is a field `config` with each of the item in its list being an object. Are there any AWS DynamoDB query methods or filter expressions to filter an item by matching the `value1` field in the `config` list? Thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 2):

`aws dynamodb scan help` is your friend, try this:

```sh
aws dynamodb scan \
    --table-name=your-table-name \
    --projection-expression="#config.value1,whateverelse" \
    --expression-attribute-names='{"#config":"config"}' \
    --expression-attribute-values='{":v1":{"N": "1"}}' \
    --filter-expression="#config.value1 > :v1"
```

If any part of path is reserved keyword then it needs to be included in `--expression-attribute-names` like in example above.